# running Rgbdslam remotely

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot, workstation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run rgbdslam on a turtlebot ( roomba 500 )

I am able to connected the Kinect to my workstation and

trying to run roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

gives ERROR:

while processing /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'

running

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam

works fine and I am able to save out ply files.

When I connect to my turtlebot and set the ROS_MASTER_URI & ROS_HOSTNAME to point to the turtlebot and try running rgbdslam on workstation I get no data feed into the rgbdslam gui.

I have tried running rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam on the turtle bot and it works, slowly.

I have also tried recording a bag file, using suggested topics mentioned on another post "Minimal Topics for RGBDSLAM", onto the workstation and the disconnecting from the turtlebot and reset ROS_MASTER_URI & ROS_HOSTNAME to the workstation start roscore and playing back the bag file on the workstation using rosrun rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam and still no topic data coming into rgbdslam.

Topics played back from bag file:

turtlebot@turtlebot-workstation:~$ rostopic list

/camera/depth/camera_info

/camera/depth/image

/camera/rgb/camera_info

/camera/rgb/image_color

/clock

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/tf

When I playback the rather large bag files, 140mb, all of the topics are published but rgbdslam will not listen.

So in effect rgbdslam only wants to work on the workstation with the kinect physically connected and roscore running with openni_launch locally.

EDIT: INTERESTING....

As a test I ran roscore,
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch  &  rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam
and recorded bag file - using SAME topics - on the WORKSTATION only and with kinect connected to it. When I playback this bag file (file size ALOT larger 1.6gb for only a few seconds.)rgbdslam recognizes the bag file topic and processes fine....

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48512/running-rgbdslam-remotely/) by [JP Schubert](https://answers.ros.org/users/3510/jp-schubert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_HOSTNAME has to point to the name of the current computer. Not to the machine where the roscore is running. It only tells the nodes under which address they are reachable from the outside.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0